# Two ways Binding between a Slider and Entry

Tags: xaml, binding, xamarin.forms

I would like to bind an Entry with a Slider and vice versa. I wrote something like this:

```
<Entry x:Name="myEntry" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"  BindingContext="{x:Reference slider}"/>
<Slider x:Name="slider" Maximum="100" Minimum="0"  BindingContext="{x:Reference myEntry}"/>
```

When I use the slider, the value in the entry is updated, but when I put manually some value in the Entry, the value append a 0 or change to 0. What can be the problem. I am working on android.

Comment: you have a BindingContext set for the Slider, but no value is actually bound

Comment: Actually, I guess you don't need to define the BindingContext to the Slider. Once you did it on Entry as TwoWay mode, it should working

Comment: thinking about this some more, you probably want to enable 2-way binding on both controls, but bind them to the same property of your VM.  You don't bind them to one another

Comment: @Jason is my method wrong? Theoretically, it should work as expected. I just do not understand the resetting to 0 that I experience when i change the value of the Entry

Answer (score 0):

You should bind both your Slider and Entry to string/ integer in a backing View Model.

```
class MyViewModel 
{
    private int _sliderValue;
    public string EntryText 
    {
        get => _sliderValue.ToString();
        set => SetProperty(ref _sliderValue, int.Parse(value) );
    }

    public int SliderValue
    {
        get => _sliderValue;
        set => (ref _sliderValue, value);
    }
}
```

And in the view

```
<Entry Text="{Binding EntryText}" />
<Slider Value="{Binding SliderValue}" />
```

[More MVVM Info](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/)

[Fresh MVVM for Xamarin](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm)

[Caliburn Micro for Xamarin](http://caliburnmicro.com/)

Comment: your lambda expression give me a lot of errors (SetProperty does not exist in the current Context). Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: it actually does not work. I implemented the SetProperty interface but it is still not working

Comment: the class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I did implement it using :PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

Answer (score 0):

please refer the following xaml code

```
<Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>
        <Entry Text="{Binding Path=Value}"
           FontSize="18"
           x:Name="label"
           BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=slider}"/>
    <Slider x:Name="slider"
            Maximum="1500"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same can be achieved by using the view model please refer the code

Xaml

```
<Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="NameEntry" Placeholder="Enter Name"  Text="{Binding Forename,Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <Slider Value="{Binding Forename}" Minimum="0"  Maximum="10"/>

        </StackLayout>

    </Frame>
```

-------------------  now see the model in a c# file-----------------------------------

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public class DetailsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        int forename;
        public int Forename
        {
            get
            {
                return forename;
            }
            set
            {
                if (forename != value)
                {
                    forename = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged ("Forename");
                }
            }


        }
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
       BindingContext = new DetailsViewModel();

    }
}
```